# About the application with the i icon at the bottom of the screen

Tags: ios6, xcode4.6

I searched for this and couldn't find any references to this.

In my iOS universal app, I wanted to display the information icon (same as the utility application) at the bottom right of my main view controller and use the same both for iPhone and iPad to flip over to display information about my app and other things. On the iPadd Utility application template with XCode 4.6, the information icon is displayed as a button on the navigation bar and a UIPopOver control is used to display information.

In my case, I don't want to use a UIPopOver on the iPad but use the same flip over effect both for iPhone and iPad when clicking the information icon. Is this a valid as per Apple's guidelines or guaranteed for rejection?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do exactly what you're thinking of doing in my app.  I used the flip transition to display my info page using the information icon as the button image.  I had no problems with Apple regarding this when I submitted.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is yours a universal app and no issues on your iPad version?